# Hyper-visor Running Above Main OS

Tags: virtual-machine, hypervisor

I would like to ask the implications of running a virtual machine management OS which runs all other operating systems below it. Instead of running VirtualBox on a host OS such as Windows or Linux, I am talking about the hypervisor being the first thing running. I am talking about type 1 such as what this image from Wikipedia is talking about:

[image: This Image From Wikipedia - Type 1]

Why would one want to use type 1 over type 2 and vice versa and what are the pros/cons of each?

To clarify, I mean for the average user as I know about uses for debugging and server management, but if the average person already had this built into their system, what would they use it for?

If anyone happens to know of any existing systems (for modern operating systems such as Windows 10) for type 1 (both free and proprietary), then that would be greatly appreciated. I already know of some type 2's such as VirtualBox and VMWare.

Comment: "hy would one want to use type 1 over type 2 and vice versa and what are the pros/cons of each." - The wikipedia article you linked to explains the differences.  What you abou that explaination don't you understand?

Comment: "If anyone happens to know of any existing systems for type 1" - Check the Wikipedia, as any suggestions we have, wouldn't be on topic.

Comment: Type 1 would require very specific hardware and thus cannot be free. It would be preferred, but due to the nature (it requiring special hardware) is only done in specific cases.

Comment: I meant for the average user, I would like to know if any average user would have a need to be able to press a hotkey and switch os' if this came built in to their computer. Now, granted I know it is useful for debugging and servers, but the average person doesn't necessarily need that. And, as for existing systems, I should clarify I meant for use with modern systems.

Comment: "I would like to know if any average user would have a need to be able to press a hotkey and switch os' if this came built in to their computer." - This question does not make sense, this button does not exist, do you understand the differences between a Type 1 and Type 2 Hypervisor?  If you boot to the virtualization layer, ( i.e. a Hyper-V VM, ESXi Host, ect ) then its Type 1 otherwise you are booting to an OS which launches the software that creates the virtualization layer and thus is Type 2

Comment: With my understanding, a type one hypervisor is like type 2, but doesn't require a host os to load it because it is the host os. Would I be right, or is it something else entirely? As for switching os', I meant switching between guest os' if multiple are running simultaneously (the hotkey would be like the Windows Key or Command Key combined with something else on the keyboard, but specifically tuned to the hypervisor on the systems that come with it).

Comment: I decided to move this [conversation to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49673/hyper-visor-running-above-main-os-clarification-chat), I just had to do it manually because the link hadn't shown up to automatically do it.